# Can quantum teleportation be used to break BB84?

Tags: teleportation, bb84

BB84 is a key quantum distribution scheme, which is supposed to be "provably secure" and resistant to an individual eavesdropper. However, from what I can tell, is seems as if one could implement a successful eavesdropping protocol that leverages quantum teleportation. Let me explain my reasoning at a high level:

First, the steps of BB84 at a very high level:

- (1) Alice generates a sequence of N qubits, each of which are randomly selected to be one of $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$, $|+\rangle$, or $|-\rangle$. The $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$ are meant to be measured using the z-basis, yielding a 0 or 1 with certainty when measured. $|+\rangle$, or $|-\rangle$ are meant to be measured using the x-basis, also yielding a 0 or 1 with certainty when measured.
- (2) This sequence of qubits is transmitted to Bob over some quantum communication channel, that may or may not have an eavesdropper (Eve) on it.
- (3) Bob measures each of his qubits with a random choice of the z or x basis state, announces this to Alice, and Alice sends Bob the list of the basis states that was to be used on each Qubit.
- (4) Alice and Bob both discard the (approximately) N/2 qubits that Bob measured with the "wrong" basis state.
- (5) Of the remaining matching qubits, Bob and Alice share the first half of the sequence with each-other. If the sequence is the same, then they can achieve some level of confidence that nobody eavesdropped, because eavesdropping would have required reading the qubits on either the x or z basis, which would have a 1/2 chance of disturbing each one. The larger the original N, the higher the confidence of a secure transmission can be.

We know that quantum cloning is not possible, and thus the transmission between Alice and Bob could not have been cloned by Eve mid-flight. However, quantum teleportation *does* exist, but it requires measuring (potentially collapsing) the state of the qubit being cloned. Could this not be used to eavesdrop while still allowing "clean" transmission of qubits between Alice and Bob?

Say that Eve is eavesdropping on the communication channel between Alice and Bob. For each Qubit that passes through this channel from Alice to Bob, Eve does the following:

- Run the input qubit through a quantum teleportation algorithm repeatedly, alternating between using the z-basis and the x-basis for the measurement step of the teleportation.

  - This of course will require reading this qubit and thus collapse it to a 0 or 1. However, the original superposition of this qubit will be preserved, in another qubit on her local quantum computer. (Eve "teleported" the qubit to herself).
  - Repeat these teleportation steps, giving the output qubit from the last round of teleportation as the input qubit to the next round. Do this until one of the z-basis or x-basis measurements disagree with a previous measurement on that basis. When this occurs for one of the bases, we know that it must have been meant to be measured in the other basis.
- Now that Eve knows both the correct basis and what the readout for the qubit in that basis was, pass the remaining teleported qubit over the network along to Bob, which should have the same superposition as it was when originally sent from Alice.

Does this break BB84?

Comment: Shortly no. I don't think the statement "However, the original superposition of this qubit will be preserved, in another qubit on her local quantum computer." - when she measures a qubit from an entangled pair she collapses the entanglement. I also think it violates the [monogamy of entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogamy_of_entanglement).  I'd recommend you draw a circuit if you can.

Comment: Unless I a mistaken, BB84 does not utilize any entanglement.

Comment: But your teleportation does.

Comment: Yes, the teleportation does utilize entanglement. However, by the time the teleportation completes, the output qubit has been fully disentangled. Thus, the entanglement is isolated to one "round" of teleportation. An entangled pair of qubits is never shared between Alice, Eve, or Bob.

Comment: I’d recommend you draw a circuit to explain your attack. Eve entangles the photon sent by Alice to one of two qubits in a Bell pair used for teleportation, then measures the qubit sent by Alice in the Z basis while measuring one of the two qubits in the Bell pair in the X basis to know how to teleport the qubit sent by Alice to her third qubit. Bob needs to get a qubit (if not he knows that Eve is listening). What does Bob get in your protocol?